# Why do I always fail when I run jobs on github actions? even though I have installed the latest version of Node on my machine

Tags: node.js, github, github-actions, workflow, semantic-release

I have installed the latest version of NodeJs (v18.14.0), but it still fails to do jobs, what should I do? this is the code from my workflow and the screenshot of the error.

```yaml
# This workflow will do a clean installation of node dependencies, cache/restore them, build the source code and run tests across different versions of node
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-nodejs

name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: ['main']
  pull_request:
    branches: ['*']

jobs:
  quality:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x, 16.x, 18.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm test

  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' }}
    needs: [quality]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run semantic-release
        env:
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

[image]

I've tried installing everything from scratch by removing node_modules and package.lock.json then I did an npm install, but the result is still the same. When pushed to the repository it always fails to run the job

Comment: Change `[14.x, 16.x, 18.x]` to `[18.x]`.

Comment: Why would the Node version on your machine matter _at all_ in the GitHub runner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strategy` is missing for the `publish` job. You have to define it under `publish` too.

Using `${{ matrix.node-version }}` is invalid here without `strategy`:

```yaml
publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # ...
    steps:
      # ...
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }} # invalid
```

You need to verify which version [`actions/setup-node`](https://github.com/actions/setup-node) installs under `publish` with that invalid value. Apparently, only the [default preinstalled Node.js 16.19.0](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#language-and-runtime) is there.

**NOTE**: [The default preinstalled NodeJS version will be set to 18 from tomorrow (Monday - February 13th, 2023).](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/7002)

---

Apart from that, the error in that image:

```
[semantic-release]: node version >=18 is required. Found v16.19.0.
```

means that this step can only run on NodeJS v18+. Installing other lower versions i.e. 14.x and 16.x would result in failures. This makes `strategy` completely redundant because you only need v18:

```yaml
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18
```

---

You might want to lint your workflows with https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ to identify potential issues.